# How to append to beginning and end of line containing a matching pattern in a file using bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I need to add a `<!--` to the beginning of a line and `-->` to the end of a line for each line in a xml file if a certain string is present. so, for example, if `BlueCard` is the string I want to match and the file looks like this currently:

```
RedCard
BlueCard
GreenCard
```

I want the new file to look like:

```
RedCard
<!--BlueCard-->
GreenCard
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/.*BlueCard.*/<!--&-->/' file
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted

Comment: Is there a way to do mud;tiple searches per file? Lets say I wanted to also append the line with RedCard with #, could I do it all at once?

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/.*\(Blue\|Red\)Card.*/<!--&-->/' file`?

Comment: Insert semicolons between each substitution commands: `sed 's/.*BlueCard.*/<!--&-->/;s/.*RedCard/#&/;' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can also match pattern and then apply substitute(`s`) for all lines that matches.

```
sed '/BlueCard/ s/.*/<!--&-->/' test
```

- `&` Here it selects everything that is matched by `.*`

Answer (score 0):

try in awk too once.

```
awk '/BlueCard/{print "<!--" $0 "-->";next} 1'  Input_file
```

So looking for string BlueCard in a line if it finds it then print the comments with that line, using next will not skip all further statements. using 1 will print everything apart from line having BlueCard as it is already taken care by the condition itself.

**Solution 2nd:** Using sub utility of awk here.

```
awk '{sub(/BlueCard/,"<!--&-->")} 1'   Input_file
```

Simply substituting string BlueCard here with the comments and printing everything then.